# How do you use ImageMagick in Perl?

Tags: perl, imagemagick

I'm trying to get the command line equivalent of "identify image.png" to work in Perl.

How do you go about doing this?

Thanks.

Update:
I have the following code

```
        use Image::Magick;      
    $image = Image::Magick->new;
    open(IMAGE, 'image.gif');
    $image->Identify(file => \*IMAGE);
    close(IMAGE);
```

But get the following error:

> Can't locate Image/Magick.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an `Identify` method method for PerlMagick as [this documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php) says.

Its parameters are: `file=>file, features=>distance, unique=>{True, False}`

So it could be used like this (**tested**):

```
use Image::Magick;

$image = Image::Magick->new;
open(IMAGE, 'image.gif');
$image->Read(file => \*IMAGE);
close(IMAGE);
$image->Identify();
```

If you need only the dimensions:

```
use Image::Magick;

$image = Image::Magick->new;
my ($width, $height, $size, $format) = $image->Ping('image.gif');
```

Comment: I just get Can't locate object method "new" via package "Image::Magick" (perhaps you forgot to load "Image::Magick"?) at image.pl line 4.

Comment: did you load the module? `use Image::Magick;`

Comment: Yeah just updated my post to reflect that, but then I get the error shown above in my edited post

Comment: You need to install the ImageMagick perl module. Here are the instructions: http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Only problem is now when I print $image, all I get is "Image::Magick=ARRAY(0x8bac968)"

Comment: The `$image` is an `Image::Magick` instance you need to print out the return value of the `Identify` method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3783/discussion-between-gbhall-and-karaszi-istvan)